# Not able to update Apple ID Settings

Tags: catalina, imac, apple-id, login

I am trying to login to my Apple ID on system iMac which is quite old (as shown below).

[image]

But whenever I try to login with my Apple ID, there are two different responses I have observed

1. If I try to login to my Apple ID immediately after restart the system, it hangs forever (as shown below)

[image]

2. If I cancel the above window forcefully and retry to login, then it shows `Unknown error occured` (as shown below)

[image]

In both the cases, I am not able to login to my iMac system. Although I am able to login on Chrome or other web browser (that means my credentials are working and correct). Can anyone suggest how can I login with Apple ID to iMac system.

Comment: Why does being able to log in to Chrome mean your Apple ID is working?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. I've had similar problems in the past when requested to re-enter my Apple ID password. I found out that temporarily disabling iCloud Keychain sometimes helped. Do you have iCloud Keychain enabled? If that's the case, could you try disabling it?

Comment: @jaume: Whenever I restart the system, not only iCloud but also I see pop-ups for the keychain and other apps immediately. Do you know how to disable them? Thanks.

Comment: I guess those pop-ups are related to your Apple ID needing verification (could you add screenshots of them?), I suppose they will keep coming up until you are able to sign in. As I said, I'd recommend that you try disabling iCloud Keychain, if that doesn't work, you could try signing out and then signing in again.

Comment: @jaume: I have checked the iCloud keychain. It is already disabled.

Comment: @SolarMike: Hello, I think if I am able to log in using an Apple ID into Chrome (or any other browser), the same credentials should work on mac devices ( iPhone/iMac/iPad, etc.). Do you mean the same Apple ID credentials may work differently on web-browser and mac devices?

Comment: My Google ID and account is different to my Apple ID. I have storage associated with my Apple ID that is not available to my Google account.